# Asyncio task creation with different accepted methods give different results

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

Having the fololowing code:

```
import asyncio

async def mycoro(number: int):
    print(f"Starting {number}")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print(f"Finishing {number}")
    return str(number)
 
c = mycoro(7)
# task = asyncio.ensure_future(c)
task = asyncio.create_task(c)
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(task)
loop.close()
```

Why do I get *sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'mycoro' was never awaited*

while:

```
import asyncio

async def mycoro(number: int):
    print(f"Starting {number}")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print(f"Finishing {number}")
    return str(number)

c = mycoro(7)
task = asyncio.ensure_future(c)
# task = asyncio.create_task(c)
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(task)
loop.close()
```

runs as expected

IF

as per https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/asyncio-task.html#creating-tasks both ways of creating tasks:

```
task = asyncio.create_task(coro())
task = asyncio.ensure_future(coro())
```

are accepted?

*Running with python3.9

Answer (score 0):

The warning is just a side effect of the **error** that occurs before the warning and which is the real issue:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hniksic/Desktop/a.py", line 11, in <module>
    task = asyncio.create_task(c)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/tasks.py", line 381, in create_task
    loop = events.get_running_loop()
RuntimeError: no running event loop
```

You can't call `asyncio.create_task()` outside of a running event loop; it is designed to be called from inside a coroutine to submit *additional* tasks to the event loop. The reason for that design is that submitting tasks to the "current" event loop (one returned by `asyncio.get_event_loop()`), as `ensure_future` does, is incompatible with `asyncio.run()`, which always creates a fresh event loop. In other words, if `asyncio.create_task(c)` at top-level submitted `c` to the "current" event loop, then `asyncio.run(other_coroutine())` would ignore `c` because it runs a different event loop. To avoid confusion, `asyncio.create_task()` requires being called from inside a running event loop.

If you want to create tasks on a particular event loop before running it with `run_until_complete()`, you can use `loop.create_task(c)` instead. Making that change removes the error.

Comment: You sound like you are right, my head is currently spinning around this asyncio so I will read more on this subject and will return to mark this as an accepted answer once I fully understand what you were saying. Thank you!

Comment: @CatHariss If you're an asyncio beginner, look into `asyncio.run()` and just call that at top-level. At the top-level of your program you shouldn't need to call `create_task()` or explicitly deal with an event loop. Many tutorials still use `run_until_complete()`, which is the older asyncio API.